# how to execute multiple unix command from python

Tags: python-2.7, unix, command

i am new to python i want to execute multiple sequential unix command using python

i.e. 1. cd desktop   ; 2.  awk '{print $1}' old.txt > new.txt  ; 3. sort -u new.txt >sorted.txt

Thank u for helping

Answer (score 0):

Create shell script and launch it from Python
Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/desktop
awk '{print $1}' old.txt > new.txt 
sort -u new.txt >sorted.txt
```

or run directly from python:

```
awk '{print $1}' | sort -u new.txt >sorted.txt
```

or use python  to sort lines

Comment: can u please elaborate i cant understand

Comment: how to create a shell script, sorry for saying

Comment: vi xxx.sh The press INSERT. PASTE Script above. Then press ":" and "wq" // All without quotes.
but as I said you can use NOSCRIPT solution

Comment: Why don't you like use Python for sorting? It's perfect for that task

Comment: Since it a 9 gb file sortinmg will take time. Thanks for ypur replies